# Can one prove $\int^b_a f(t) \ dt = - \int^a_b f(t) \ dt$ ? Similarly can one prove $\int^a_a f(t) \ dt = 0$ ? Is equality only by definition in both?

Tags: integration

Can one prove $$\int^b_a f(t) \ dt = - \int^a_b f(t) \ dt$$ ? Similarly can one prove $$\int^a_a f(t) \ dt = 0$$ ? Is equality only by definition in both?

I've learned that $\int^b_a f(t) \ dt$ represent the equal values of the lower and upper integrals (supremum and infimum with respect to lower and upper sums of partitions). Also a partition is defined as follows: $$a = x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n = b$$, which imply $a < b$.

So how does one make any sense of the equalities above ? Can one prove them by means of theory (please show me how), or why have people chosen these definitions ?

Comment: Common sense?­­

Comment: the real question is: what is this integral when $a>b$?

Comment: That $\int_a^b = -\int_b^a$ is a matter of definition.

Comment: Please check the question .Very similiar http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261244/is-there-a-fundamental-reason-that-int-ba-int-ab

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you use Riemann sums,
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{b-a}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} f\left(a+k \frac{b-a}{N}\right),$$
then swapping $a$ and $b$ reverseing the order of the sum using $k=N-j$, you will get the same expression but with a minus sign (up to a small error term that goes away in the limit).

Comment: So what you get is $$\int_b^a f(x) dx = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{a-b}{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} f\left(b+(N-j) \frac{a-b}{N}\right),$$ ?

Comment: Distribute $(N-j)$ to get the same argument in the function as originally written. Also note the bounds should be $j=1$ to $j=N$, hence the comment about an error term that goes away with the limit. You have to add and subtract $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ respectively.

Comment: Does this "prove" the integral with these bounds ?

Comment: What I am saying is that using this definition you get $\int_a^b = -\int_b^a$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $$\int_a^b f(t)dt+\int_b^c f(t) dt=\int_a^c f(t) dt $$ thus if $c=a$ rigth hand side become zero and we are done.

$$\int_a ^a f(t)dt$$ being zero is clear from many aspect.

Comment: But if $c = a$ then one of your integrals on left hand side is undefined ?

Comment: @user111854: I think that is why we define it in that matter. But nayrb's answer is more clear. it is like why $0!=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(x)=\int f(x)dx$ (Indefinite)

then your first equation is $F(b)-F(a)$ (Arbitrary constant gets cancelled).

I assume you can carry on from here. And those partitions need are true even if inequalities don't hold but we like to define it that way as integral from a to b represents area under curve from a to b. Just google geometrical significance of integral.