# Show $\int_a^b f(x)dx = - \int_b^a f(x)dx$.

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

How to show $\int_a^b f(x)dx = - \int_b^a f(x)dx$ using the definition of Riemann integration?

$\int_a^b f(x)dx :=  \lim_{||P(x,t)|| \rightarrow 0} \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} f(t_i) (x_i - x_{i-1}) $, where $P(x,t)$ is a tagged partition of $[a,b]$. But the definition of a partition assumes $ a = x_0 \leq x_1 ... \leq x_{n-1} \leq x_n = b 
 \Rightarrow a \leq b$, so then how is $\int_b^a f(x)dx$ defined if $ b > a$?

Comment: This is usually a _definition_ (for $a<b$, once then defines $\int_b^af$ as $-\int_a^bf$), since intervals $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ imply $x_{i-1}\le x_i$.

Comment: So are you saying that $\int_b^a f(x)dx :=-  \int_a^b f(x)dx$ for $b > a$?

Comment: Exactly. This definition, together with $\int_a^a f = 0$, is useful as it ensures that another important property, $\int_a^bf = \int_a^cf + \int_c^bf$, is valid _in general_ and not only for $a<c<b$.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: You're welcome; I turned this into an answer.

Comment: Please check my answer about it .https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261244/is-there-a-fundamental-reason-that-int-ba-int-ab/261328#261328

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the usual definition to make sense, you need a non-empty interval $[a,b]$ (which implies $a<b$) and then you have a definition for the definite integral of $f$ over $[a,b]$, denoted as:
$$\int_a^bf$$
Notice that this definition does not make sense for $b=a$ (since there is no interval to partition) and not for $b<a$ (since the partitioning requires $a<b$; that's how intervals work).

Using this definition, you can prove the following important property:
$$\int_a^bf = \int_a^cf + \int_c^bf \tag{$*$}$$
With the usual definition, this property holds only for $a<c<b$. To allow more flexibility, one could want to give meaning to integrals of the form $\int_a^af$  and $\int_b^af$ (with $a<b$).

If we define them as:
$$\int_a^af := 0 \quad \mbox{and} \quad \int_b^a f:=-\int_a^b f$$
then the formula $(*)$ remains valid and holds in general, for **all** $a,b,c$.

> How to show $\int_a^b f(x)dx = - \int_b^a f(x)dx$ using the definition of Riemann integration?

Long story short: this is usually a definition, not a property you prove. We define it in such a way that another important property remains valid in general.